# Designing view on top of multiple embed views

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have the task to design a application that has a main view which is always visible (it has a button on it's bottom side, and when pressed a image displays on top of all views), and a set of TableControllerView's that should appear under it, and the user needs to be able to navigate through them.

I know that you can embed a view inside another, but you cannot refer more than one view to it. The current way I'm trying to do now load one TableViewController inside the embed view, and when the user clicks the cell I manually load the other controller and add it as a child of the main view, which is the RootViewController. The problem with this approach is that the navigation bar gets stuck using the root view controller, so I have to manipulate the main navigation items on each subview transition, and second is that the frame for the second view I load is coming as it had full size, making some cells be under the main view button. This way doesn't uses segues for transition, so it makes the storyboard kinda useless.

I was thinking into using a TabViewController with it's tab hidden, but wanted to ask here for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered, a TableViewController likes to fill up the whole screen (except navigation bars, tab bars, status bar, etc. which are official Cocoa Touch GUIs). When you want a table view to fill only part of the screen, you are supposed to use a UITableView but not a UITableViewController. You set your custom view controller object (subclass of UIViewController, not UITableViewController) as the table view delegate and data source. You will need to duplicate part of the functionality of UITableViewController in your custom view controller, but it's not a lot more than you have to do already to supply the data.

You should probably follow the standard design pattern and have separate view controller objects for each of the "pages" the user can navigate to. You just have a main button and image on each of them. But I could imagine why that might not give you exactly the effect you want.

Comment: I don't agree with this, the table view controller doesn't require full screen, you just need to tell it what frame it has and, preferably, add it as a child view controller. OP could even use a navigation controller which doesn't occupy the whole screen...

Comment: Table View Programming Guide for iOS: "If the view to be managed is a composite view in which a table view is one of multiple subviews, you must use a custom subclass of UIViewController to manage the table view (and other views). Do not use a UITableViewController object because this controller class sizes the table view to fill the screen between the navigation bar and the tab bar (if either are present)."

Comment: I believe that refers to the situation where you want the table view controller subclass to itself manage multiple subviews. Not the situation where the table view that it manages is one of many subviews.

Comment: "because this controller class sizes the table view to fill the screen": this will apply to both those situations. I mean it might be possible to make it work the way you describe, but you are swimming against Apple's stream.